# Debugging ajax, resend request

Tags: javascript, ajax, debugging

This is something that I've been looking for for a while. When I'm debugging my ajax applications I have to keep reloading the whole page, even if the only changes I made were on the server.

For example, in my current application, there is Tinymce being loaded, jQuery UI, I have to click one dialog, to click another to click another. What I would love is the ability in something like Firebug to right click the request and select 'resend' especially when the only change I made is on the server e.g. `print_r( $_POST );`

The closest I've gotten to this ability is in Firebug on the Net tab, right click the request and click 'open in new tab', which is nearly there - but not quite

Comment: yes, I'm also using the "new tab" feature. What's wrong about that? You want a "resend" - but this is not simple resend, your javascript code must process the request then - so it is more like calling some function of your code, more than feature of the debugger itself (if I understood you well). This you can accomplish from the FireBug console.

Comment: hi, I'm using FF with FireBug. My aim is to resend exactly the same request as easily as possible, so when I make changes on the server script only I don't have to refresh the page. How do you accomplish this from the FireBug console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replay the HTTP request, thats something firebug isn't meant to do. You need fiddler to get the work done. Fidder2 even has a Firefox addon. You can replay your request using fiddler.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but it only works on windows :( and I use linux. I did come across a FF addon => live-http-headers ( http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/ ) for linux but this doesn't give a good way of reading the response. It doesn't format any json responses for testing, just opens the response in a new tab.

Comment: Current Firefox version also supports resend of ajax requests in the developer toolbar (F12). And then click on "network Analysis". Click on the request you want to resend. There is a button "edit and resend".